# Blazor Server application with ASP.NET Core Identity -windows Authentication

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I need a Blazor Server application with ASP.NET Core Identity.
In the Application it should be possible

- to authenticate with Windows authentication and login to ASP.Net Identity with the corresponding user in the identity table
- to authenticate with ASP.Net Identity

Is there any recommended example or tutorial to implement this

Comment: Visual Studio gives you this out of the box. When you create your project, choose Individual Accounts as the auth type. There are zillions of examples and tutorials around if you get stuck. If you have a specific problem, feel free to post back, but you're unlikely to get much help here with such a broad question that can be answered with a bit of searching. Not trying to be rude, I'm trying to help you find the answers you need.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel , Really Appreciate your answer , My question not about how to create Authentication , its about merge between windows and Individual Authentication   
. for example when login via windows , search in Identitytables and login via identity .

Comment: Ah my mistake, misread your question. Sorry, I can't help you there. Hope you find your answer though

Comment: @SouhailMaatouk did you ever find an answer to this?